# Circular Doubly Linked List, Print Function

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to create a circular doubly linked list with a sentinel node which is supposed to read data from a file and insert it in the list, than perform some operations with it. For now I'm stuck on a simple print function which won't print from a list for some reason. The data in the file is in the form of strings, 
example: "Popular Sorting Algorithms,
          Bubble Sort, Merge Sort, "empty line", etc

Here is my code so far:

Header file contains:

```
typedef struct NODE {
 struct NODE *prev;
 char *value;
 struct NODE *next;
} NODE;

typedef struct LIST {
 int count;
 struct NODE *next;
 struct NODE *prev;
 } LIST;

int InsertEnd(NODE *head, char * value, int *lineCount);
void printLines(int *lineCount);
void Traverse(NODE *head);
```

Main contains:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "header.h"


int main()
{
    int lineCount = 0;
    NODE *head;

    head = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE)); /* creates head node dynamically */

    head->next = NULL;   /* points to first element */
    head->prev = NULL;   /* points to last element */
    head->value = "HEAD"; /* not needed, but it was pretty useful when debugging */

    //*********BEGIN OF OPEN FILE FUNCTION
    FILE* fp;
    char *fname = NULL;
    fname = (char *)malloc(200); <<<<<===== I would prefer to set the size dynamically adjusting but I dont know how

        printf("Reading file input.txt\n");

    //Checks if the file us unable to be opened, then it shows the error message
    if ( !(fp = fopen("input.txt", "r")))
    {
        printf("\nError, Unable to open the file for reading \n");
        exit(100);
    }

    //*********BEGIN OF READ FROM FILE FUNCTION

    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        fgets(fname, 150, fp);  //reads the file and stores in buffer

        fname[strlen(fname) - 1] = '\0'; // reduces empty strings for input

        if (fname != '\0')
        {

            InsertEnd(head, fname, &lineCount);
        //printf("%s\n", head->next->value);  <<<<==== If uncomment this print function would work properly but only in this context

        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error'\n"); // For debugging
        }

    }
    Traverse(head); // Print Function Should Be Working in Here
    printf("Debugging print\n");
    printLines(&lineCount); // Shows Line Count
    return 0;
}
// Function inserts a new node at the end of the LIST
int InsertEnd(NODE *head, char * value, int* lineCount)
{
    int lineCounter = *lineCount;
    /* create new node */
    NODE *newnode;
    newnode = (struct NODE *)malloc(sizeof( struct NODE));
    newnode->value = value;
    /* placing new node in LIST */
    if (head->next == NULL) /* LIST was empty */
    {
        newnode->next = head;
        newnode->prev = head;
        head->next = newnode;
        head->prev = newnode;
        lineCounter++;               // Increment line counter
    }
    else /* LIST wasn't empty */
    {
        newnode->next = head;
        newnode->prev = head->prev;
        head->prev->next = newnode; /* adjust node that was previously last */
        head->prev = newnode;       /* adjust head node */
        lineCounter++;                // Increment line counter
    }
    *lineCount = lineCounter;
    return lineCount;
}


// This function prints how many lines there are in the LIST, but I need to get rid of the empty spaces
void printLines(int *lineCount)
{
 printf("Line counter is %d", *lineCount);  // Shows the number of lines, but doesn't skip empty ones.
}


void Traverse(NODE *head)
{
    NODE *current = head;

    printf("Forward:");
    while (current!= head->prev)
    {
        printf("%s \n", current->value);

        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Therefore, I have several problems so far:

1) I need to get rid of empty strings in my list most likely. What would be a better approach, to get rid of them while reading or just not displaying when printing? How would I do this exactly?

2) How can I fix my print(traverse) function and whats wrong there?

3) Additionally all of this should be going on through the menu manager which would prompt for a command ( I got this right I think). But there are some functions that I don't know how to implement. For example when used hits "I" it should call Insert functions and prompt the user to enter two more values  and , and later insert   at the appropriate . How would I do that? Example "I 1 8"

4) Similarly to the previous one, there should be List function which should print lines between specific values. User input format should be "L  to " list inclusively. Example "L 2 5"

5) Similarly to previous there should be a delete function with the format "D  " inclusively. Example "D 3 7"

6) And the very last is the Save function in the format "S " Example "S output.txt"

Thank You for the help!

Comment: You can add this to your list of things to address: [`while (!feof(fp))` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong). And the ensuring `fgets()` is completely unchecked for potential failure before assuming it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least these issues in your code,

In `main()`

```
 if (fname != '\0')
```

this should be

```
 if (fname[0] != '\0')
```

---

In `InsertEnd()`

```
newnode->value = value;
```

should be

```
newnode->value = strdup(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In you code there should be some correctness which is very help full first as per your request you need to allocate buffer dynamically but not know `file` length so it can be achived by this one

```
int sz;
printf("Reading file input.txt\n");

//Checks if the file us unable to be opened, then it shows the error message
if ( !(fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r")))
{
    printf("\nError, Unable to open the file for reading \n");
    exit(100);
}

fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
sz = ftell(fp);

printf("size of file %d\n",sz);

fname = (char *)malloc(sz);
rewind(fp);
```

Now for reading content from file you checked `fname` to `\0` which is not correct i corrected your `while..loop`.

```
while (!feof(fp))
{
    if(fgets(fname,256, fp) != 0)
    {
        fname[strlen(fname) - 1] = '\0'; // reduces empty strings for input
        InsertEnd(head, fname, &lineCount);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error'\n"); // For debugging
    }
}
```